# Angular 6 Animate CSS when element appears not on page load

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using animate.css library in my index.html head tag in my Angualar 6 application.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
```

Everything is working and I am using like so:

```
<div class="animated bounce delay-2s">
```

The only issue is, the animation is starting on page load and not when the element becomes visible.

How can I make the element animate when the user has finally scrolled to the element, and then it begins its animation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try using the [css3-animate-it](https://github.com/Jack-McCourt/css3-animate-it) library. It makes it very easy to display the animations when in view. Take a look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animations.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
            .box {
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                background-color:#aaaa00;
                margin:150px auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="animatedParent">
            <div class="animated bounceInDown box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="animatedParent">
            <div class="animated fadeIn box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="animatedParent">
            <div class="animated growIn box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="animatedParent">
            <div class="animated bounceInRight box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="animatedParent">
            <div class="animated fadeInDown box"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css3-animate-it.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each of the animations should only trigger once they are in view (once the parent "animatedParent" class is in view as that's how this library works).

This library also has many animations available, more information can be found [here](http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/).

Comment: My issue isn't getting it to work, I have it working. Though, the animations are starting on page load, not when the div comes into view. I tried your library and it didn't not solve it :/

Comment: @user10181542 my example should work as expected, i.e. the animations animate only when in view, but there seems to be some problems with the cdn files. I've updated my code which will now use local js and css files; use the same code from my answer, but download the source files from [here](http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/), place them in the correct directory and then give it a go, it should work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it works as the page loads, but not as the element comes into the screen. So if I have an animated div in the footer, the animation plays while my page loads and I'm looking at the header, making the animation go unnoticed :/

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure what you're doing then. Go on to [this](http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/) website and the animations should only animate when they come into view.